# Checking each character for a number

Tags: java, string

I am trying to loop through a string and check each character if one of the characters is a number. If it is a number, I want to return it as true. I have a string "crash", though it returns it as true (that it has a number).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public boolean isNumber()
{
  String newString = "crash";
  boolean isNumber = true;
  for (int i=0; i<newString.length(); i++)
  {
     if (Character.isDigit(newString.charAt(i)))
     {
        isNumber = true;
        continue; // continue looping through the string. Go on to the next index.
                  // The character at index i is a number.
     }
     else
     {
        isNumber = false; 
        break; // terminate the for-loop and return it as false! It is not a number!
     }
   }
  return isNumber;
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. My logic seems to be fine, but my coding isn't.

EDIT: I figured it out. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The better way to do this is to use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String%29) to try an parse the string as an int and see if that works.

Comment: I tried running your code and it gives me the correct answer ... false ... can you post the code that u are using to test this function as well

Comment: Odd... I tried running this and it came up false!

Comment: Works just fine: http://www.ideone.com/54mFZ.  Are you sure the code you posted above is the exact same code you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran that code and I get `false`, as expected. Please double-check that you’re running it correctly.

Here’s a simpler way to express that function, by the way:

```
public boolean isNumber(String string) {
  for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: (Or, indeed, `public boolean isNumber(String string) { return string.matches("\\d+"); }`.)

Comment: Beat to me it while I was typing. This is the best iterative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code [should work correctly](http://ideone.com/eCKSE), although I would probably use this instead:

```
public boolean isNumber(String newString)
{
    for (int i=0; i != newString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(newString.charAt(i))) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// a regex equivalent
public boolean isNumberRegex(String newString)
{
    return newString.match("\\d+");
}
```

The method above checks if *all* characters are digits.

If I misunderstood your question and you want to check if *any* of the characters is a digit:

```
public boolean hasNumber(String newString)
{
    for (int i=0; i != newString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(newString.charAt(i))) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// regex equivalent
public boolean hasNumberRegex(String newString)
{
    return newString.match(".*\\d.*");
}
```

Comment: there is a minor bug here ... the idea is to locate a number in the string ... thus jatin146 should return true as it has a number in it ... yours will return false

Comment: @jsshah I understood this as a method that should only return true if all characters are numbers.

Comment: @jsshah: The OP's description doesn't agree with their code o_O

Comment: @jsshah At any rate, I amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `Integer.parseInt("string")` and catch the exception.

```
try {
     int num = Integer.parseInt("string");
     return true;
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     return false;
}
```

Or another way with regEx:

```
if ("string".replaceAll("\\d+","").length() > 0) { 
    //false 
} else { 
    //true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly... but since you're using the same variable "isNumber", and continuing when you get a positive match... the result you'll return will always be of the last character of the String, except when you get a non numeric character, in which case, you exit right away.

Do you want to check if the whole String is a number? Or if it contains a number?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNumber(String str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    boolean isNumber = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            return true;
    }

    return isNumber;
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to my `hasNumber` function

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work, but to my mind, setting a variable and then breaking just to return it is ugly. (I know other coders like this; IMHO they are wrong.) I also dislike introducing unnecessary test variables, like NullUserException's solution. I would just return directly.

[*EDIT*: This code is the same as Brockman's]

```
public boolean isNumber() /* Note: returns true for empty string */
{
String newString = "crash";
for (int i=0; i<newString.length(); i++)
{
   if (!Character.isDigit(newString.charAt(i)))
   {
    return false; /* non-digit detected */
   }
 }
return true; /* all characters were digits */
}
```