# Preventing a String from getting integer values in Java

Tags: java, string, swing, int

Is there a possible way to do that?

e.g In my application form a have a field for the user's name which is a **String**. But how can I disallow the user from giving for example **"L3bron James"** instead of giving  **"Lebron James"**?

```
String sql_name = name.getText();
// name is a JTextField
if (sql_name.length() == 0)
    {
        //how to check if the name does not contain int digits
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name is a string ,NOT an Integer, not a null value!!","Invalid Name",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: You can control it programatically in runtime. If input is a number, delete this char from form field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking each character for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655432/checking-each-character-for-a-number)

Comment: There are key event listeners.

Comment: And document event listeners.

Comment: Be aware that there are some **valid** names that contain an integer. For example see [Men's Names and Titles](http://www.emilypost.com/communication-and-technology/social-names-and-titles/294-mens-names-and-titles):

When a man is named after his father who is a "Jr.," he is called "the third," once written with either the numeric **3rd** or the Roman numeral III but now confined almost exclusively to the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression on the string to see if it contains number characters:

```
if (Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(sql_name).find()) {
    // Show error message
}
```

Comment: does `Pattern` need an import?

Comment: I mean it compiled but still the 2014 for string was accepted when it shouldn't

Comment: Could you show the code you used? The code above should work. Just verified that it gives the expected results here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to filter for integers. Following this answer [How to filter string for unwanted characters using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945695/how-to-filter-string-for-unwanted-characters-using-regex) you can use regex to check for integers and prompt the user again if you found an integer. Or you could just replace them which would be kind of rude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils.isAlphaSpace](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphaSpace%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) from apache commons

```
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace(null)   = false
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("")     = true
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("  ")   = true
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("abc")  = true
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("ab c") = true
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("ab2c") = false
StringUtils.isAlphaSpace("ab-c") = false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution**

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sql_name.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(sql_name.charAt(i)))
                flag = true;// number exists in the string
            }
if (flag == true)
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name is a string ,NOT an Integer, NOT a null value!!","Invalid Name",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```